# How to convert a concrete integer into a generic integer?

Tags: rust

I have the following function:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use num::traits::Unsigned;

fn test<T: Unsigned>(strings: Vec<String>) -> HashMap<String, T>{
    let mut string_map: HashMap<String, T> = HashMap::new();
    for (i, string) in strings.iter().enumerate() {
        string_map.insert(string.clone(), i);
    }
    string_map
}
```

that causes the following compilation error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs
   |
   |         string_map.insert(string.clone(), i);
   |                                           ^ expected type parameter, found usize
   |
   = note: expected type `T`
              found type `usize`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

Although the `Unsigned` trait is implemented only for unsigned integer types, the compiler is not able to recognize this.
How can I cast `i` to `T`, since `i as T` is not working either?

Comment: What happens if you call e.g. `test::<u16>` and thus have a `HashMap<String, u16>` but try to insert a `usize` from `enumerate()` into it?

Comment: @justinas: When I remove the generic parameter and replace `T` with `u16`, I can use `i as u16`, without getting a compilation error

Comment: I don't know if this is a simplified version of your problem but, `Enumerate::next()` will always produce tuple with `usize`.Why do you need a generic type on that function ?

Comment: Your hashmap value isn't generic, it's an `usize`, so you must replace the `T` with `usize`

Comment: @Ömer Erden: In my project this is a method embedded into a struct, that should work for all unsigned integers. Using only `usize` is not possible, because I also want large vectors (millions to billions elements) of the same type.

Comment: I believe you need to use this kind of a structure : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b2d23e1afd99779a7bcd18872f3036bb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as` only does primitive casts between built-in numerical types, but `Unsigned` can be implemented for your own types, etc. That's why `as` does not work.

You can utilize the `TryFrom` trait:

```
use num::traits::Unsigned;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::convert::TryFrom;

fn test<T>(strings: Vec<String>) -> HashMap<String, T>
where
    T: Unsigned + TryFrom<usize>,
    <T as std::convert::TryFrom<usize>>::Error: Debug, // only for unwrap()
{
    let mut string_map: HashMap<String, T> = HashMap::new();
    for (i, string) in strings.iter().enumerate() {
        string_map.insert(string.clone(), T::try_from(i).unwrap());
    }
    string_map
}

fn main() {
    let result: HashMap<_, u16> = test(vec!["abc".into(), "def".into()]);
}
```

In theory, you could use `From` instead of `TryFrom`, but in practice, most integer types, e.g. `u8`, `u16`, `u32` are not guaranteed to fit `usize`. So `TryFrom` and error handling is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need a concrete type, you can hide it but in your example it's always be usize so you can do:

```rust
use num::traits::Unsigned;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn test(strings: Vec<String>) -> HashMap<String, impl Unsigned> {
    strings
        .into_iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, s)| (s, i))
        .collect()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this problem, instead of converting from `usize` to `T`, is to not use `enumerate` and instead bound `T` such that it can be the counter.

```
use num::{Integer, Unsigned};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn test<T: Clone + Unsigned + Integer>(strings: Vec<String>) -> HashMap<String, T> {
    let mut string_map: HashMap<String, T> = HashMap::new();
    let mut i = T::zero();
    for string in strings {
        string_map.insert(string, i.clone());
        i = i + T::one();
    }
    string_map
}
```

`T` has two new bounds:

- `Clone` is necessary to be able to insert a clone into the map and keep iterating with the counter;
- `Integer` allows you to use `T::zero()`, `T::one()` and addition.

Be aware the behavior of this solution depends on the overflow behavior of `T`, while [justinas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666173/3650362) will always panic if `i` goes out of range (or can be rewritten to return a `Result`, which may be more desirable).